# Disabling maintenance mode Command returned non-zero exit code

Tags: module, error, extensions, production-mode

I am a newbie in magneto I made a Magento custom extension but while uploading this into the Magento Marketplace, I am facing an issue it's Test Fail, Below is the test report

Environment: PHP 7.1.22 Magento 2.2 CE

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Enabling maintenance mode
Starting compilation
Something went wrong while compiling generated code. See the error log for details.

> Disabling maintenance mode Command returned non-zero exit code:
>   `/usr/bin/php -f /var/www/html/bin/magento setup:di:compile`

can anybody help me in this I am happy to pay as well

Regards

Comment: Before deployment do run the below commands

Comment: rm -rf generated
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
That's all you required for module installation and all

Comment: I just update the question to make this elaborate can you please thorught question again once

Comment: Can you run php bin/magento setup:di:compile enabling your module and check for any compilation errors in your module

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran sure doing this now few minutes

Comment: @RajMohanR I tried that, this is fine